# При наведении на блок появляется другой, при этом первый блок должен остаться фоном для второго

Tags: html, css

Все очень запутанно, поэтому прилагаю скрин и кусок кода html. Нужно написать css. Не понимаю, можно ли обойтись без js. В общем, объяснил, как смог, если чего не понятно, спрашивайте.
Код:

```
 <li>
    <div class="home-active">
        <img src="img/img.jpg">
        <div>
            <h2>ололоол</h2>
            <div class="read-more">посмотреть</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

http://skripter.info/uploads/forum/images/2014-09/1410891550ffd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gaa6rgd0/

http://jsfiddle.net/b1baew00/

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вопрос решен:)